# SVG inline title in H1 for SEO

Tags: seo, html, ranking, heading, svg

I would like to use in my `H1` a SVG inline using title to put my text/keyword.
eg:

#### The classic way

```
<h1>My Title</h1>
```

#### My idea

```
<h1>
 <svg>
  <title>My Title</title>
  <path>....</path>
 <svg>
</h1>
```

Would the `H1` have the same SEO impact as using the SVG inline method?

Comment: Keep in mind that the 'title' element should be into the 'head' element of the HTML document, not into the 'body'. The 'title' is the text appearing in the browser tab and in the search results. The 'h1' is the element you use as text to describe your page, you use it into the 'body' and it should be only informative, not a link. Below the 'h1' you insert the content and the other headings ('h2'... 'h6'). Content headings must be textual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend this. The `H1` tag is designed to be a text headline.

Making your H1 an SVG **will not** have a positive impact for SEO.

H1: "Primary Headline" with your target keyword *somewhere* within it **will** have a positive impact for SEO.

To get the best results, use natural language in your headline including related/synonymous variants of your primary keyword (which you should use in your `<title>` tag.)

Optimal Structure:

```
<head>
     <title>Page Title</>
     <meta name="description" content="Description of page" />
</head>
<body>
     <h1>Page Headline</h1>

[your content]

</body>
```

Comment: Ok I understand that I should not use svg in my h1.
But do you mean I should use : `<h1><title>My title</title></h1>` instead of `<h1>My Title</h1>` ?

Comment: @zkokk No don't do that. See my edit in answer.